# PCRE match string between two brackets

Tags: php, regex

in php I want to match the string: name if it was contained between (( ))

I tried:

```
/\(\((.*)\)\)/U
```

and it works perfectly but if the string was between three brackets it fail
so (((name))) or (((name)) doens't work

how to write a regexp for that?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: same result when using [(]{2,3} I want to match the string if it is between (( )) and want to ignore the other brackets

Comment: you need to use the non-greedy quantifier on your .* as I've indicated in my answer below. Otherwise .* eats everything including the closing parens. example: (.*?)b  matches `aaaa` out of `aaaab` but (.*)b will match `aaaab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular expression you can quantify the number of times something appears with `{min,max}` following the token. ie.

```
\({2,}(.*?)\){2,}
```

This matches 2 or more ( on the left and 2 or more ) on the right. Leaving the 2nd value of `{min,max}` blank means "min matches to infinite matches" so it will match ((((((((string))) or any variation as long as there are 2+ parens on each side.

Answer (score 1):

`\({2,}(.*?)\){2,}`

Will match greater than 2 leading or trailing brackets.

Comment: I need to only match the strings between (( )) can't just remove the brackets because the input string is text and might contain a lot of strings between () that I don't want to touch

Comment: @Bassel Safadi, updated to match a minimum of 2 outer brackets.

Comment: Should it not be: `\({2,}(.*?)\){2,}` where there has been a `)` after `.*?`

Comment: @RobertPitt that's true, please check Erik answer above it has \\) at the end

Comment: @robertpitt aye i lost a bracket in the edit, and only noticed the leading one missing. thanks, updated.

Comment: Yea for some reason SO Stripped my backslashes, lets test, Single: `\(\)` Double: `\\(\\)`, Ill report this minor bug